# How/where/when do I must call to MongoClient close?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am developing a web application in java and I have a doubt about closing MongoClient.

Seeing this
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/#getting-started-with-java-driver

> The MongoClient instance actually represents a pool of connections to
>   the database; you will only need one instance of class MongoClient
>   even with multiple threads. See the concurrency doc page for more
>   information. The MongoClient class is designed to be thread safe and
>   shared among threads. Typically you create only 1 instance for a given
>   database cluster and use it across your application. If for some
>   reason you decide to create many MongoClient instances, note that: all
>   resource usage limits (max connections, etc) apply per MongoClient
>   instance to dispose of an instance, make sure you call
>   MongoClient.close() to clean up resources

and this
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/#java-driver-concurrency

> The Java MongoDB driver is thread safe. If you are using in a web
>   serving environment, for example, you should create a single
>   MongoClient instance, and you can use it in every request. The
>   MongoClient object maintains an internal pool of connections to the
>   database (default maximum pool size of 100). For every request to the
>   DB (find, insert, etc) the Java thread will obtain a connection from
>   the pool, execute the operation, and release the connection. This
>   means the connection (socket) used may be different each time.

It seems that I must have an only instance of MongoClient. My doubt is: How/where/when do I must call to MongoClient close?

Thanks

Comment: Almost never. And "never" in server instance program.

Answer (score 6):

[The API doc](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.10.0/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#close%28%29) says:

"closes the underlying connector, which in turn closes all open connections. Once called, this Mongo instance can no longer be used. "

So, I would assume, that you only close it when you never want to open a MongoDB connection again (during this runtime). In other words, only at the end of the lifecycle of the application that uses this client instance.

Comment: A corner-case where it would make sense to close the MongoClient object before shutdown would be when the application only requires data from the database at startup and then works with a local copy without ever contacting the database again.