# Closing `MongoClient`

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm wondering if calling `close` on Java's [`MongoClient`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html) will wait for the currently running queries to finish, or will it close the connections immediately and thus abort the currently running operations.

I've look into the source code and it doesn't seem like there is something that will wait for the queries to stop, but I not sure if I've check all of the places.

Comment: See this post: [How/where/when do I must call to MongoClient close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165059/how-where-when-do-i-must-call-to-mongoclient-close)

Comment: The problem isn't if I should call it or not - I know that I have to do it. Basically what I need is a away to abort all queries that are currently running in the application without the need to shutdown the application itself. The application itself is resilient to disconnects so it wont be a problem that I do a force-disconnect by hand.

Comment: Closing the `MongoClient` closes all the connections (of the connection pool) - that mght stall all your queries. But, what is that scenario one wants to abort the all the running queries.